# Scrolling the page up in React

Tags: reactjs

In my component, i wanna scroll the page up when the user click on `Link` Component witch will change the url and therefore what user sees.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const RelatedMovieItem = props => {
    const movie = props.movie;
    
    return (
        <div className="card" style={{width: "18rem",marginTop: "10px", padding: 0, marginLeft: "10px"}}>
          <img src={movie.imageUrl} className="card-img-top" alt={movie.name} />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{movie.name}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">{movie.description}</p>
            <Link to={`/movies/${movie.id}`} className="btn btn-primary">Go to details</Link> //once this clicked i want to scroll the page up
          </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default RelatedMovieItem;
```

How to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if every route changes you want to scroll top you can do it using `<ScrollToTop>` passing children down the tree like that.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <ScrollToTop>
    <Switch>
      // your route
    </Switch>
  </ScrollToTop>
</BrowserRouter>;
```

And create component `ScrollToTop.js`

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop({children}) {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `window.scrollTo(0,0)` by passing it to the `onClick` attribute.

This way your page will scroll to the top left whenever you click on `<Link />`.

```
<Link
  to={`/movies/${movie.id}`}
  className="btn btn-primary"
  onClick={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}
>
  Go to details
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a reference and attach it to the component you want to scroll to.
Then onclick you can call `ref.current.scrollIntoView()`